# __shfl_down and __shfl_down_sync give different results

Tags: cuda, gpu

I am confused by  __shfl_down and __shfl_down_sync , they give different results.

```
__global__ void shufledown1(double* a, double *b,double *c, int N)
{
    double  temp = 2.0;
    __syncthreads();

   for (int offset = 32/2; offset > 0; offset /= 2){
         temp+=__shfl_down(temp, offset,32);
   }
    printf("%d %f %d \n",threadIdx.x ,temp,blockDim.x * gridDim.x);
}
__global__ void shufledown2(double* a, double *b,double *c, int N)
{
    double  temp = 2.0;
    __syncthreads();

   for (int offset = 32/2; offset > 0; offset /= 2){
       temp+=__shfl_down_sync(temp, offset,32)
   }
    printf("%d %f %d \n",threadIdx.x ,temp,blockDim.x * gridDim.x);
}
```

The first one gave:

```
0 64.000000 64 
'''''
''''
''''
63 64.000000 64
```

The second one gave:

```
0 33.000000 64
'''''
''''
''''
63 33.000000 64
```

The kernel was run with 1 block 64 threads.
Regards

Comment: How are you launching  the kernels? There is only a very limited set of cases where it would be normal to expect the same results. Please edit an [MCVE] into your question

Comment: 64.00000 is very different from 33.00000.

Comment: The functions do different things (or more accurately, the meaning of the arguments is different). The results shouldn't be the same. If you aren't going to show how you ran the kernel then it is not possible to explain the exact results you have and why the results are as they are

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In addition to just a different name, the `_sync` versions of the warp shuffle functions also have a different prototype, as indicated in [the documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#synopsis).  The first parameter is a mask parameter.

You appear to be trying to use both functions in the same way:

```
     temp+=__shfl_down(temp, offset,32);

temp+=__shfl_down_sync(temp, offset,32);
```

but that is incorrect.   To use the `_sync` version in an analogous fashion, you should do:

```
temp+=__shfl_down_sync(0xFFFFFFFF, temp, offset,32);
```

When I make that change, your code runs correctly for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void shufledown1(double* a, double *b,double *c, int N)
{
    double  temp = 2.0;
    __syncthreads();

   for (int offset = 32/2; offset > 0; offset /= 2){
         temp+=__shfl_down(temp, offset,32);
   }
    printf("%d %f %d \n",threadIdx.x ,temp,blockDim.x * gridDim.x);
}
__global__ void shufledown2(double* a, double *b,double *c, int N)
{
    double  temp = 2.0;
    __syncthreads();

   for (int offset = 32/2; offset > 0; offset /= 2){
       temp+=__shfl_down_sync(0xFFFFFFFF, temp, offset,32);
   }
    printf("%d %f %d \n",threadIdx.x ,temp,blockDim.x * gridDim.x);
}


int main(){
    double *a = NULL, *b = NULL, *c = NULL;
    shufledown1<<<1,64>>>(a, b, c, 0);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    shufledown2<<<1,64>>>(a, b, c, 0);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_60 -o t1358 t1358.cu
t1358.cu(9): warning: function "__shfl_down(double, unsigned int, int)"
/usr/local/cuda/bin/..//include/sm_30_intrinsics.hpp(453): here was declared deprecated ("__shfl_down() is deprecated in favor of __shfl_down_sync() and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-declarations to suppress this warning).")

ptxas /tmp/tmpxft_000045b6_00000000-5_t1358.ptx, line 49; warning : Instruction 'shfl' without '.sync' is deprecated since PTX ISA version 6.0 and will be discontinued in a future PTX ISA version
ptxas /tmp/tmpxft_000045b6_00000000-5_t1358.ptx, line 52; warning : Instruction 'shfl' without '.sync' is deprecated since PTX ISA version 6.0 and will be discontinued in a future PTX ISA version
ptxas /tmp/tmpxft_000045b6_00000000-5_t1358.ptx, line 63; warning : Instruction 'shfl' without '.sync' is deprecated since PTX ISA version 6.0 and will be discontinued in a future PTX ISA version
ptxas /tmp/tmpxft_000045b6_00000000-5_t1358.ptx, line 66; warning : Instruction 'shfl' without '.sync' is deprecated since PTX ISA version 6.0 and will be discontinued in a future PTX ISA version
ptxas /tmp/tmpxft_000045b6_00000000-5_t1358.ptx, line 77; warning : Instruction 'shfl' without '.sync' is deprecated since PTX ISA version 6.0 and will be discontinued in a future PTX ISA version
ptxas /tmp/tmpxft_000045b6_00000000-5_t1358.ptx, line 80; warning : Instruction 'shfl' without '.sync' is deprecated since PTX ISA version 6.0 and will be discontinued in a future PTX ISA version
ptxas /tmp/tmpxft_000045b6_00000000-5_t1358.ptx, line 91; warning : Instruction 'shfl' without '.sync' is deprecated since PTX ISA version 6.0 and will be discontinued in a future PTX ISA version
ptxas /tmp/tmpxft_000045b6_00000000-5_t1358.ptx, line 94; warning : Instruction 'shfl' without '.sync' is deprecated since PTX ISA version 6.0 and will be discontinued in a future PTX ISA version
ptxas /tmp/tmpxft_000045b6_00000000-5_t1358.ptx, line 105; warning : Instruction 'shfl' without '.sync' is deprecated since PTX ISA version 6.0 and will be discontinued in a future PTX ISA version
ptxas /tmp/tmpxft_000045b6_00000000-5_t1358.ptx, line 108; warning : Instruction 'shfl' without '.sync' is deprecated since PTX ISA version 6.0 and will be discontinued in a future PTX ISA version
$ ./t1358
0 64.000000 64
1 64.000000 64
2 64.000000 64
3 64.000000 64
4 64.000000 64
5 64.000000 64
6 64.000000 64
7 64.000000 64
8 64.000000 64
9 64.000000 64
10 64.000000 64
11 64.000000 64
12 64.000000 64
13 64.000000 64
14 64.000000 64
15 64.000000 64
16 64.000000 64
17 64.000000 64
18 64.000000 64
19 64.000000 64
20 64.000000 64
21 64.000000 64
22 64.000000 64
23 64.000000 64
24 64.000000 64
25 64.000000 64
26 64.000000 64
27 64.000000 64
28 64.000000 64
29 64.000000 64
30 64.000000 64
31 64.000000 64
32 64.000000 64
33 64.000000 64
34 64.000000 64
35 64.000000 64
36 64.000000 64
37 64.000000 64
38 64.000000 64
39 64.000000 64
40 64.000000 64
41 64.000000 64
42 64.000000 64
43 64.000000 64
44 64.000000 64
45 64.000000 64
46 64.000000 64
47 64.000000 64
48 64.000000 64
49 64.000000 64
50 64.000000 64
51 64.000000 64
52 64.000000 64
53 64.000000 64
54 64.000000 64
55 64.000000 64
56 64.000000 64
57 64.000000 64
58 64.000000 64
59 64.000000 64
60 64.000000 64
61 64.000000 64
62 64.000000 64
63 64.000000 64
0 64.000000 64
1 64.000000 64
2 64.000000 64
3 64.000000 64
4 64.000000 64
5 64.000000 64
6 64.000000 64
7 64.000000 64
8 64.000000 64
9 64.000000 64
10 64.000000 64
11 64.000000 64
12 64.000000 64
13 64.000000 64
14 64.000000 64
15 64.000000 64
16 64.000000 64
17 64.000000 64
18 64.000000 64
19 64.000000 64
20 64.000000 64
21 64.000000 64
22 64.000000 64
23 64.000000 64
24 64.000000 64
25 64.000000 64
26 64.000000 64
27 64.000000 64
28 64.000000 64
29 64.000000 64
30 64.000000 64
31 64.000000 64
32 64.000000 64
33 64.000000 64
34 64.000000 64
35 64.000000 64
36 64.000000 64
37 64.000000 64
38 64.000000 64
39 64.000000 64
40 64.000000 64
41 64.000000 64
42 64.000000 64
43 64.000000 64
44 64.000000 64
45 64.000000 64
46 64.000000 64
47 64.000000 64
48 64.000000 64
49 64.000000 64
50 64.000000 64
51 64.000000 64
52 64.000000 64
53 64.000000 64
54 64.000000 64
55 64.000000 64
56 64.000000 64
57 64.000000 64
58 64.000000 64
59 64.000000 64
60 64.000000 64
61 64.000000 64
62 64.000000 64
63 64.000000 64
$
```

For new code or new maintenance, you should only use the `_sync` versions.

For further examples of the usage of the mask parameter, refer to this [blog](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/using-cuda-warp-level-primitives/)

Comment: thank you, it works for me too. But what is the meaning of the  mask "0xFFFFFFFF" in the new function.

Comment: Did you read the documentation I pointed out?  For example, this paragraph: "The new *_sync shfl intrinsics take in a mask indicating the threads participating in the call. A bit, representing the thread's lane id, must be set for each participating thread to ensure they are properly converged before the intrinsic is executed by the hardware. All non-exited threads named in mask must execute the same intrinsic with the same mask, or the result is undefined."

Comment: I have read it. But I can't understand how to use the mask and the lane id.

Comment: If you want to emulate the behavior of the old non-`_sync` instruction, just use `0xFFFFFFFF` as I have shown.  If you want to understand more about the new instructions it's probably time for a new question.  There are also [blogs](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/using-cuda-warp-level-primitives/) and [presentations](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2017/presentation/s7622-Kyrylo-perelygin-robust-and-scalable-cuda.pdf) which discuss this new feature in CUDA 9.  Try reading the blog, it is informative.

Comment: As an alternative, you could pass -1 to the mask to set all bits: `temp+=__shfl_down_sync(-1, temp, offset,32);`