# Is mask adaptive in __shfl_up_sync call?

Tags: cuda, shuffle, intrinsics

Basically, it is a materialized version of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58833808/insight-into-the-first-argument-mask-in-shfl-sync). Suppose a warp need to process 4 objects(say, pixels in image), each 8 lanes are grouped together to process one object:
[image]
Now I need do internal shuffle operations during processing one object(i.e. among 8 lanes of this object), **it worked for each object** just setting `mask` as `0xff`:

```
uint32_t mask = 0xff;
__shfl_up_sync(mask,val,1);
```

However, to my understanding, set `mask` as `0xff` will force the `lane0:lane7` of object0(or object3? also stuck on this point) to participate, but I ensure that above usage applies to each object after a mass of trials. So, my question is whether `__shfl_up_sync` call can adapt argument `mask` to force corresponding lanes participating?

**Update**
Actually, this problem came from codes of [libSGM](https://github.com/fixstars/libSGM/tree/master/src) that I tried to parse. In particular, it solves minimal cost path with [dynamic programming](https://github.com/fixstars/libSGM/blob/master/src/path_aggregation_common.hpp#L27-L93) in a decently parallel way. Once program reaches this [line](https://github.com/fixstars/libSGM/blob/master/src/vertical_path_aggregation.cu#L51) after launching the kernel [`aggregate_vertical_path_kernel`](https://github.com/fixstars/libSGM/blob/master/src/vertical_path_aggregation.cu#L27-L28) with execution configuration:

```
//MAX_DISPARITY is 128 and BLOCK_SIZE is 256
//Basically, each block serves to process 32 pixels in which each warp serves to process 4.
const int gdim = (width + PATHS_PER_BLOCK - 1) / PATHS_PER_BLOCK;
const int bdim = BLOCK_SIZE;
aggregate_vertical_path_kernel<1, MAX_DISPARITY><<<gdim, bdim, 0, stream>>>(...)
```

An object `dp` is instantiated from `DynamicProgramming<DP_BLOCK_SIZE, SUBGROUP_SIZE>`:

```
static constexpr unsigned int DP_BLOCK_SIZE = 16u;
...
//MAX_DISPARITY is 128
static const unsigned int SUBGROUP_SIZE = MAX_DISPARITY / DP_BLOCK_SIZE;
...
DynamicProgramming<DP_BLOCK_SIZE, SUBGROUP_SIZE> dp;
```

Keep following the program, [`dp.updata()`](https://github.com/fixstars/libSGM/blob/master/src/vertical_path_aggregation.cu#L106) will be invoked in which `__shfl_up_sync` is used to access the last element of previous `DP_BLOCK` and `__shfl_down_sync` is used to access the first element of the rear `DP_BLOCK`. Besides, each 8 lanes in one warp are grouped together:

```
//So each 8 threads are grouped together to process one pixel in which each lane is contributed to one DP_BLOCK for corresponding pixel.
const unsigned int lane_id = threadIdx.x % SUBGROUP_SIZE;
```

Here it comes, once program reaches this [line](https://github.com/fixstars/libSGM/blob/master/src/path_aggregation_common.hpp#L57-L58):

```
//mask is specified as 0xff(255)
const uint32_t prev =__shfl_up_sync(mask, dp[DP_BLOCK_SIZE - 1], 1);
```

**each lane in one warp does shuffle with the same mask `0xff`**, which causes my above question.

Comment: I don't believe "each lane in one warp does shuffle with the same mask `0xff`".  is a true statement.  The mask does not appear to be the same value across the warp.  See [here](https://github.com/fixstars/libSGM/blob/master/src/vertical_path_aggregation.cu#L57).  `group_id` changes across the warp.

Comment: OK, I got it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its confusing when you do this:

```
lane0:lane7 | lane0:lane7 | lane0:lane7 | lane0:lane7
```

because a warp doesn't have 4 sets of lanes, that are numbered lane 0 to lane 7.  It has one set of lanes, numbered 0 to lane 31.

```
lane 31 | lane 30 | ... | lane 0
```

Note that I have ordered the lanes this way because that corresponds to the bit order in the `mask`.  It should be evident which bit corresponds to which lane.  bit 0 in the `mask` parameter corresponds to lane 0, and so on.

This confusion is compounded by the fact that you are only specifying 8 bits, i.e. 8 lanes, in your `mask`:

```
uint32_t mask = 0xff;
```

If you want the warp to have a correct possibility to use all 32 lanes to process all 4 objects, you must specify a 32-bit `mask`:

```
uint32_t mask = 0xffffffff;
```

There is no "adaptation" of an 8-bit `mask` to apply to each group of 8 lanes in the warp.  You must explicitly specify the `mask` for each of the 32 lanes.  This is true even if the `width` parameter is used (see below).

If you want to cause the shuffle operation to work only in an 8-bit group (with 4 logical shuffles) that is what the `width` [parameter](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#warp-shuffle-functions) is for:

```
T __shfl_up_sync(unsigned mask, T var, unsigned int delta, int width=warpSize);
                                                               ^^^^^
```